# Scrollbar position offset inside of a Bootstrap v 3.2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've already read a few question-answer pairings on Stack, all of which advocate wrapping your overflowing content element inside of a different `div` element in order to make it look like the scrollbar from the first element has been offset from its right edge. The below question illustrates my goal graphically: [CSS: Possible to "push" Webkit scrollbars into content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719895/css-possible-to-push-webkit-scrollbars-into-content).

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 dropdown" id="filter1">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">    
    Button Name
  </button>
  <div class="formatting_wrapper">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation" class="disc_menu filter"><a role="menuitem">Option 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="disc_menu filter"><a role="menuitem">Option 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I wrap the above `<ul>` element inside of an extra div (`.formatting_wrapper`), it does allow me to create the illusion that I've offset the scrollbar.

My problem is that the toggle button no longer functions properly: It will open and close correctly, but only once. After that it retains the `focus` / `open` border and will not de-activate or open a second time. Essentially it freezes.

What can I do if I want to retain the scrollbar formatting AND keep BS working as intended? I tried to look into the `dropdown.js` for BS but I'm kind-of a javascript novice.

Cheers

**Edit:** Here is a working example of my problem in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vercingetorix333/4hcdk25a/3/).

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of your problem? http://www.bootply.com/new# for example

Comment: @Sebsemillia: Added a fiddle for you in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: You can make the 'dropdown-menu' element behave as your wrapper element too. http://jsfiddle.net/4hcdk25a/9/

Comment: @Celmar: Your suggestion doesn't solve the problem. The only way I can find to offset the scrollbar from the right edge of the element is to embed it within another div element whose background color is the same as the child element's and then add padding. Your scrollbar is still up against the right edge.

Comment: adding transparent border is not helping?

Comment: @tmg: I was adding a border to the trackbar and that did nothing. What **does** work however, I've discovered, is to add a transparent border to the _thumb_ scroller. This is a solution which I haven't been able to find anywhere on Stack; surprising since the question has been asked ~4 times already.

Comment: I meant to add transparent border to "ul.dropdown-menu". Can you show an updated jsfiddle with the solution you discovered to educate us?

Comment: @tmg: see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's close to perfect for what I needed: By altering some of the `::webkit-scrollbar` values, I was able to create the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/Vercingetorix333/q8fmzmv6/). My goal was to produce a scrollbar which appeared to be offset from the right margin. Because I couldn't wrap it in a `div`, I did the following:

1) Adjusted the width of the scrollbar to make it wider (let x = width).

2) Added a border to the `thumb` which has the same color as the background. Border must be less than x/2, otherwise it occludes the `thumb's` background color entirely.

Note 1: I tried to make the border transparent but it seemed to let the `thumb's` background color show through, eliminating the offset effect.

Note 2: Adding the border will not only make the thumb look like it's offset from the edge, it will also offset it by the same amount from the top and bottom of the frame.

I exaggerated the amount of offset in my fiddle to highlight the method.